# Can I modify html passing through openvpn server?

Tags: openvpn

I am a beginner of OpenVPN. Recently, I have succeeded setting an OpenVPN server for my team.

Now I want to let my team members know whether they are using VPN or not by showing a notice in the browser, so that I would like to modify the HTMLs passing through the VPN server.

How can I achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Comment: Just to say but OpenVPN is a bit outdated, I would switch to Wireguard, it can be done easily. Anyways your question is very interesting. Since you have control over the cloud server perhaps you can add a css icon that is fixed to be in the top right corner of the page?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Yes, the css icon is what I want, exactly. And thank you for introducing the Wireguard, I will take a look.